# How to avoid double borders on list of divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of divs which are used as a FAQ. Sometimes the divs are listed below each other, sometimes there is text between them.
When they are listed below one other, I have this issue with double borders which I don't know how to solve.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYPR6/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="faq">
<div class="faqheader">Toggle 1</div>
  <div class="faqcontent">Content 1</div>
</div>

<p>Some text...</p>

<div class="faq">
<div class="faqheader">Toggle 2</div>
  <div class="faqcontent">Content 2</div>
</div>

<p>Some text...</p>

<div class="faq">
<div class="faqheader">Toggle 3</div>
  <div class="faqcontent">Content 3</div>
</div>

<div class="faq">
<div class="faqheader">Toggle 4</div>
  <div class="faqcontent">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.faq {width:200px;border: 1px solid #ddd;}
.faqheader {height:20px;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;}
.faqcontent {display:none;height:50px;}
```

The divs need to have a border: `border:1px solid #ddd`

The borders look fine when there's text between the divs (toggle 1 and 2), but when they are close together (toggle 3 and 4), it doesn't look very nice.

Changing the markup is not an option at this point. They are generated dynamically. Is there any way to fix this issue with either css or jquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add this rule to your **CSS**

```
.faq + .faq
{
    border-top: none;
}
```

**Explanation:** `.faq` that comes directly after another `.faq` dont get a top border.

1. this is a pure CSS solution (without Script)
2. it doesnt assume anithing about the layout (the div's dont have to be last childs of a container, or at some specific index)
3. its fixes the double border issue even if their are multiple `.faq` one after each other.
4. its a cross browser solution.

See this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/bYPR6/6/)

Comment: This is pretty slick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add this to the list of my snippets.

Answer (score 2):

You sure can use jQuery to do this:

```
$('.faq').each(function(){
    if($(this).next('.faq').length > 0){
        $(this).css({borderBottom:0});   
    }
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/bYPR6/2/)

For each `.faq`, if there is another `.faq` following, remove this bottom border.

Comment: This one seems like an option. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can do it with a simple CSS selector. why use Script?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add margin-top:5px; (or less) in .faq :

```
.faq {width:200px;border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-top:5px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wm7q7/

Answer (score 0):

```
.faq:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: and what if the layout changes and its no longer the third element?

Comment: He didn't say that this was dynamic example. I thought it was static. If the border styling is dependent upon what's inside of the divs, then I guess it's better to go with jQuery's CSS method

Comment: you dont have to write a Script for this. I gave a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply use a negative margin ?

```
.faq {width:200px;border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-top:-1px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bYPR6/7/

Comment: Indeed, but you simply lose 1px before each .faq element, it may not be a problem, or it can be adjusted on other elements. However your solution is pretty much better +1 ;)